# why does the second print (my_print_2) print nothing?

Tags: c, printf, c-strings

A string is scanned from the user (in `main`), and the function `isComplicated` is called (only its beginning is shown here).
Can someone please explain why the second print (`my_print_2`) prints nothing?
The first print (`my_print_1`) works fine and prints the scanned string.

Thanks.

```
bool isComplicated(char *str) {

    int length = 0;

    printf("my_print_2 %s \n", str);
}

/////////////////////////////

int main() {

    char str[N] = { 0 };

    printf("Please enter your string and a non-negative 
           integer...\n");

    if (scanf("%s%d", str, &k) != 2 || k < 0)
        exit(1);

    printf("my_print_1 %s \n", str);

    if (isComplicated(str))
        printf("Complicated \n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems you mean printf("my_print_1  %s\n", str); and  printf("my_print_2  %s\n", str);

Comment: The variable `str` is not declared in `main`. Your code doesn't compile. It is also missing the `#include` directives. Please always paste [complete, yet small code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: isComplicated() should have a return value

Comment: How is `N` defined? Did you include `<stdio.h>`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is full of bugs that are so trivial that the compiler should detect them all.

Investigate how to enable warnings in your compiler and then understand them and finally fix them properly.

For GCC, this means adding the compile options `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

If you have difficulties understanding the error messages from the compiler, you are welcome to ask here. Fixing the trivial mistakes in your current code is something you should generally do before asking here, and by trivial I mean those mistakes that the compiler detects.